# jwt token valiation always return 401 in NESTJS

Tags: nestjs

```
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';
import { Request as RequestType } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  static jwtService: JwtService;
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
        JwtStrategy.extractJWT,
      ]),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      jsonWebTokenOptions: {
        ignoreNotBefore: true,
      },
      secretOrKey: jwtConstants.secret,
    });
  }

  static async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.sub, username: payload.username };
  }

  private static extractJWT(req: RequestType): any {
     return req.cookies.access_token;
  }
```

Controller:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
@Get('posts/category/:categoryName')
async getPostsByCategory(@Res() res, @Param('categoryName',) categoryName) {
    const posts = await (await this.postService.getPostsByCategory(categoryName)).toArray();
    if (!posts) throw new NotFoundException('Post does not exist!');
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(posts);
}
```

I am not sure why it is always returning 401 in jwt strategy

jwt-auth-guard:

```
import {
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  handleRequest(...args: Parameters<InstanceType<ReturnType<typeof AuthGuard>>['handleRequest']>) {
    console.log('args ', args);
    return super.handleRequest(...args);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
err  null
user  false
info  JsonWebTokenError: invalid token
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, your extractor shouldn't be verifying the token, only retrieving it for the passport framework to verify it later.

If you're still getting a 401 after updating the extractor function, you can add this to the custom guard that `extends AuthGuard('jwt')` to get more information from what's happening:

```js
handleRequest(...args: Parameters<InstanceType<ReturnType<typeof AuthGuard>>['handleRequest']>) {
  console.log(args);
  return super.handleRequest(...args);
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach but still the same error. It says "No auth token" but I am sending the token

Comment: I stand by what I said. Your extractor function shouldn't validate/verify the token, it should only get it from the place on the request it will be found. Other parts of passport will worry about validating the token for you. Without knowing what your request is, there's nothing else I can do to help

Comment: Forgot to update the question. I am not extracting it. I am just retrieving it but still getting the same error

Comment: I am following this as reference: https://tigran.tech/nestjs-cookie-based-jwt-authentication/

Comment: You verify that `req.cookies.access_token` is there, but you `return req.cookies.token`, so most likely you are returning `undefined` and passport is seeing no token to validate

Comment: Updated the question. I am getting `invalid token` error

Comment: Is the token expired? Is it a properly signed JWT? Have you verified it in a JWT debugger like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)